# System alert recognition in appium

Tags: appium

Appium doesn't seem to recognize the system alerts like normal elements. I have an alert box with only "Ok" button.

I have tried the following but nothing seems to work.

1. Add implicit wait conditions to find the elements as :

   ```
   driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(25,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
   MobileElement clickOK= (MobileElement) driver.findElement(By.id("android:id/button1"));
   ```
2. `Thread.sleep(10)`
3. ```
   driver.switchTo().accept().alert();
   alert.accept();
   ```

How to handle the system alerts?

Answer (score 0):

Usually Appium on Android are handles alerts as regular elements, so I suggest taking page source snapshot and inspect alert:

```java
System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());
```

When you found it and get the right resource-id, you wait for it like this:

```java
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30); //30 seconds should be enough?
WebElement alertButton = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("<full resource-id with package>")));
alertButton.click();
```